# Do webgl uniforms attributes set when changing program?

Tags: javascript, webgl

Do I have to set the uniforms/attributes etc each time I switch programs or render? Such as the lines below? Or can I just set them up once when initialized?

```
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texCoordBuffer);
        //gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.attrCell.a_texCoord);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.attrCell.a_texCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.uniform2f(this.uniformCell.u_resolution, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.posCoordBuffer);
        //gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.attr.a_position);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.attrCell.a_position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + 0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texture[0]);
        //gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        //gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        //gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
        //gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
        gl.uniform1i( this.uniformCell['u_image'], 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one set of attributes per webgl context and each shader program has its own set of uniforms. Basically, attributes are global variables that all shader program has access to, and each shader program has its own instance of uniform variables.

For example, if you set an attribute using shader #1, and when you switch to shader #2, you dont need to re-set the attribute again if you are using the same attribute. If you set an uniform in shader #1, then when you switch to shader #2, you need to set the uniform in shader #2 even if the uniform are the same. However, if you switch back to shader #1, and you are still using using the same uniform set previously, you dont need to re-set it again since you already set it the first time.

Also be aware that both the uniform and attribute locations are per shader program. For example, the uniform location for texture may not be the same for two programs that use the same texture. Same for attribute locations.

Comment: hm.. Would I have to bindbuffers and set bufferdata for both shader programs? Or can the buffers I create be used in either shader program?

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texCoordBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    0.0,  0.0,
    1.0,  0.0,
    0.0,  1.0,
    0.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  0.0,
    1.0,  1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);